# Is there an efficient way to look for all the characteristic subgroups of a group in GAP?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, gap

> Is there an efficient way to look for all the characteristic subgroups of a group in GAP?

I'm only interested in finite groups.

The best I can do so far is collect all the normal subgroups into a list and check one-by-one if they are characteristic. Honestly, I haven't tried how slow this method is on finite groups of large orders, but feels like it should be quite slow.

Is there a smarter way?

What if we tighten our conditions and only look for certain characteristic subgroups for example characteristic cyclic subgroups or maybe even abelian ones?

Comment: I would suggest to try it for an order with many groups. If it takes only some seconds, this should be efficient enough.

Comment: I suspect that to do this you need to compute ${\rm Aut}(G)$, which will be one of the bottlenecks for larger groups. Of coursxe some groups have a huge number of normal subgroups, which will also cause problems!

Comment: There is a function `CharacteristicSubgroups, which calculates $Aut(G)$ and the. Tests all normal subgroups. Short of proclaiming groups of unique properties (o.g. Only one of particular order) as characteristic for free, I don’t think there is a better way.